# how to get upstream build information in a script step of jenkins classic ui pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have an old classic ui jenkins pipeline. now i need this pipeline to be triggered on the completion of other pipelines. And get the upstream pipeline information in this old pipeline.

I know how to set the upstream build trigger in the jenkins pipeline. However i cannot find a way to get the upstream build information (eg, project name, git commit).

When i output the env variables in downstream pipeline, i can only see the `BUILD_CAUSE=UPSTREAMTRIGGER` which is not useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Trigger Downstream Job With Parameters**
The old job would need to be updated to be parameterised, then you can pass the required information as parameters when you [build](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) the downstream job.

*Example:*

```
build job: "DOWNSTREAM_JOB_NAME",  
parameters: [string(name: 'upstreamJobName', value: env.JOB_NAME),  
string(name: 'upstreamJobVar', value: "${upstreamJobVar}"]
```

**Trigger Downstream Job Without Parameters**
When parameters are not being send from triggering upstream job, then we can get some of the upstream information in the downstream job like this:

```
currentBuild.upstreamBuilds[0].projectName
```

All available methods for upstreamBuilds information can be found [here](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however, i donot have the permission to modify the upstream job to add this build step. I can only configure the downstream job to add a upstream trigger of the old pipeline.

Comment: In this case I believe you can only get limited information from the upstream. I updated my answer.